# Limitation of Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider the following problem

[image]

I did it as follows. We want to optimize
$$\begin{align*}
I(x)=∫ |\dot{x } |² d t. 
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$
By Lagrange multipliers, this is the same as optimizing
$$\begin{align*}
ζ (x )& =∫_{}^{} |\dot{x } |² d t - λ ∫ (|x|-1)² d t \\
 &  = ∫  |\dot{x } |² - \lambda(|x |-1)² d t
\end{align*}\tag{2}$$
where for $$p(x)= ∫ (|x |-1)² d t,\tag{3}$$  we have  $p=0$ defining the set of points which is our constrain. Applying the Euler-Lagrange equations:
$$\begin{align*}
0 & = \frac{d}{d t}(\frac{∂  f}{∂ \dot{x }  })- \frac{∂  f}{∂  x }    \\
 &  =2 [\ddot{x }-λ x +  \frac{λ }{|x |x }  ],
\end{align*}\tag{4}$$
meaning
$$\begin{align*}
\ddot{x }=λ  x (1 - \frac{1}{|x |} ).
\end{align*}\tag{5}$$
This can’t be right. The model answer considers $p= ∫ x ·  x -1$ giving an end result
$$\begin{align*}
\ddot{x }+  |\dot{ x } |² x =0
\end{align*}\tag{6}$$
which is as required.

It has been mentioned to me that this has to do with something in the order at which we approach zero, but I am not sure.

Can someone clarify as to what is going on here? That is, why does the first choice of $p$ not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: The problem with OP's constraint function
$$ \chi ~:=~(\sqrt{x^2}-1)^2 $$
is that the gradient $\nabla\chi=0$ vanishes on the constrained [hypersurface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersurface) $\chi=0$. This forces the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ in the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) to be mathematically ill-defined/infinite. E.g. this leads to $\infty\cdot 0$ in OP's EL eq. (5). See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109398/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Here is a better approach. Let us square the constraint$^1$ in the following way

$$ \forall t:~~x(t)^2~=~1\tag{A}$$

to avoid square roots. Repeated differentiations wrt. $t$ yield

$$ x\cdot \dot{x}~\stackrel{(A)}{=}~0,\tag{B}$$

and

$$ x\cdot \ddot{x}+\dot{x}^2~\stackrel{(B)}{=}~0.\tag{C}$$

Using the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) the extended functional reads$^1$

$$ \widetilde{I}[x,\lambda]~:=~\int\! dt ~\widetilde{L}, \qquad 
\widetilde{L}~:=~\dot{x}(t)^2 +\lambda(t) (x(t)^2-1). \tag{D}$$

The [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) becomes

$$ \ddot{x}~=~\lambda x, \tag{E}$$

so that the Lagrange multiplier is

$$ \lambda~\stackrel{(A)}{=}~\lambda x^2~\stackrel{(E)}{=}~x\cdot \ddot{x}~\stackrel{(C)}{=}~-\dot{x}^2.\tag{F}$$

Altogether, we obtain OP's sought-for equation

$$ \ddot{x}~\stackrel{(E)+(F)}{=}~-\dot{x}^2 x. \tag{G}$$

---

$^1$ Since the constraint (A) applies for all $t$, note that the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda(t)$ is in principle a function of $t$.
[Eq. (A) is really infinitely many constraints, one for each $t$; so we need infinitely many Lagrange multipliers $\lambda(t)$, one for each $t$.] This fact seems to clash with OP's definition (v3) of $p$ as an integral over $t$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer.I seem to have gotten my self confused. I thought that $\lambda$ is an independent parameter by which we multiply our restriction?

Comment: Also, say I said my condition was instead $(|x|-1)^2=0$. Proceeding with your method I get a different answer. I am not sure this fail to give the same result as I don't seem to be diferentiating $\lambda$.

Comment: Hi, thank you  for the edit. So what I have as answer differs to the desired because $\lambda$ is dependent on $t$ and hence if I were to find $\lambda$ and substitute it in, I should get the same answer as yours?

Comment: An analogous result is obtained by considering $|x|'=\frac{\dot x x}{|x|} = 0\Rightarrow \dot x x = 0\Rightarrow \ddot x x+\dot x^2 = 0$. Now from the Euler-Lagrange condition $2\ddot x +\lambda x = 0$. Multiplying by $x$ this equation we obtain $2\ddot x x + \lambda = 0\Rightarrow \lambda = 2\dot x^2$ hence finally $\ddot x + \dot x^2 x = 0$

Comment: Apologies but my question still seems to be unanswered. My question is what is wrong with what I have.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: The correct Euler-Lagrange condition is $$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot x}\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0
$$
instead of
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot x}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) = 0
$$

Comment: @Cesareo: Thanks. Edited.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. That makes more sense now. Just a quick question. Is it true in general that the method of lagrange multipliers fails if the gradient is zero on the constraint, and if so why?

Comment: @MathsWizzard The Lagrange multiplier method is proved using the implicit function theorem which requires that the gradient of your constraint function not vanish on its corresponding level set.